# How to run 3 counters simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, counter, simultaneous

I'd like to run simultaneously 3 different counters following a very specific pattern:

- `counter_3` displays the number of iteration from 0 to 2144
- `counter_1` increases by 1 every 65 iterations
- `counter_2` goes from 1 to 65, then starts back from 2 to 65, then from 3 to 65 ...

The result should look like this:

```
counter_1   counter_2   counter_3

    0          1            0
    0          2            1
    0          3            2
    0          4            3
    0          5            4
    ...        ...          ...
    0          65           64
    1          2            65
    1          3            66
    1          4            67
    ...        ...          ...
    1          65           128
    1          3            129
    2          4            130
    2          5            131
    ...        ...          ...
    32         64           2142
    32         65           2143
    32         65           2144
```

I know how to run these counters separately.

For `counter_1` and `counter_3` (refered below as `i`):

```
counter_1 = 0

for i, e in enumerate(range(2145)):
        if i > 1 and i % 65 == 0:
            counter_1 += 1
        print(counter_1, i)
```

For `counter_2` (refered below as `e`):

```
n = 0
g = 1
while n <= 2145:
    for e in np.arange(g, 66):
        print(e)   
    g += 1
    n += 1
```

QUESTION: How can i run these 3 counters simultaneously ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "simultaneously"?

Comment: Do you need the counters to change during every iteration, or can you just calculate them when needed? Given any value of `counter_3` it's trivial to calculate the other two counters with some modular arithmetic.

Comment: @ekhumoro by "simulateneously" i mean during the same iteration. I'd like to see the 3 counters "evolving" at the same time like in the example above.

Comment: So can derive the other two values with the `divmod` function from the first value.

Comment: Your sample data is not consistent with your description.

Comment: @StephenRauch the snippets above do exactly what i'm describing... but separately.

Comment: @solub You said "0 to 2145" but counter_3 runs to 2144

Comment: In your data `counter_1` has the value 1, 64 times.

Comment: Why the large numbers? Couldn't you have asked the same question with smaller numbers so that you could've shown the entire output explicitly and it would be easier to compare?

Comment: Why is `counter_2` 65 twice, at the very bottom?

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks for noticing, I corrected the example.

Comment: @ubadub Because in its next-to-last round it goes from 64 to 65 and then in its last round it goes from 65 to 65.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third counter is just the index and first counter is index/65. Only the middle counter is a little less trivial, so I'd use that one to drive this.

```
for c, b in enumerate(b for start in range(1, 66) for b in range(start, 66)):
    print c / 65, b, c
```

And an itertools version:

```
for c, (_, b) in enumerate(combinations(range(66), 2)):
    print c / 65, b, c
```

Comment: `c / 65` gives a float where I need an int and it should increase by one every 65 iterations.

Comment: No it doesn't give a float. The division would give a float in Python 3, but my code is obviously Python 2 code and doesn't run at all in Python 3 without modification (because `print` needs parentheses there). Not sure why I used Python 2, maybe because Prune did. Anyway, in Python 3 just use `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention I was using Python 3. That's a great answer !

Answer (score 4):

You have the right general idea: determine when you have to fiddle with the counters.  However, note that `coutner1` is a value you can derive simply from `counter3` with integer division.  Just worry about `counter2`, and you're fine.  Here's a solution more at your level of coding:

```
c2 = 65
c2_new = 0   # Track where to start counter2 next time

for c3 in range(2145):

    if c2 == 65:
        c2 = c2_new
        c2_new += 1

    c2 += 1
    c1 = c3 // 65   # Simple division gets the c1 value

    print c1, c2, c3
```

Comment: @Scott Hunter: Thanks; I was looking at another question, and noticed the formatting error about 10 seconds before you fixed it.

Comment: Many thanks ! I don't really understand all the downvotes to my question.

Comment: @solub: ask on the main question, not here -- I certainly didn't down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Not looking for the simplest or slickest specific answer to your question, I wanted to offer a pattern that might be applied more broadly.

You could use a generator to provide each of the series of numbers that you want, then combine them. This means that you could test them independently. It also means that you could parameterise each of them to allow for smaller numbers during testing. Here, for instance, `Counter_1` is parameterised so with the number of repetitions allowed before its behaviour changes.

`Counter_2` is almost certainly more complicated than it needs to be. My brain is in a fog.

```
def Counter_1(rep=65):
    n = -1
    while True:
        n += 1
        k = n//rep
        yield k

def Counter_2(rep=65):
    n = 0
    inc = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        if n==rep:
            k = n//rep
            yield n
            inc += 1
            n = inc
        else:
            yield n

counter_1 = Counter_1()
counter_2 = Counter_2()

for counter_3 in range(2145):
    c_1 = next(counter_1)
    c_2 = next(counter_2)
    print (c_1, c_2, counter_3)

    if counter_3>10:
        break
```

Comment: I think it should be `if counter_3>2145` at the end. Anyway, im new to Python and your answer is a great opportunity for me to learn more about generators. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome. The two lines at the end are there only to limit the number of lines that are printed. I should have explained that. In the final code they would be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Another iterative approach using generator functions (in Python 3).

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


def counter1(item=0):
    """Yield increments every 65 iterations."""
    for _ in range(1, 66):
        yield item
    yield from counter1(item+1)


def counter2(item=1, stop=66):
    """Yield `item` to 65, incrementing `item` after `stop-1`."""
    yield from range(item, stop)
    if item != stop:
        yield from counter2(item+1)


def counter3(stop=2150-5):
    """Yield numbers 0 to `stop`."""
    for item in range(stop):
        yield item


cts = list(zip(counter1(), counter2(), counter3()))
```

**Demo**

```
# Sample results (see OP results)
counters = it.chain(cts[:5], cts[63:68], cts[128:132], cts[-3:])
for iteration in counters:
    print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(*iteration))
```

Sample Output

```
0          1          0         
0          2          1         
0          3          2         
0          4          3         
0          5          4         
0          64         63        
0          65         64        
1          2          65        
1          3          66        
1          4          67        
1          65         128       
1          3          129       
2          4          130       
2          5          131       
32         64         2142      
32         65         2143      
32         65         2144
```

---

**Details**

- `counter1`: an *infinite* generator; yields a value for over a range of numbers.  Repeat for incremented values recursively.
- `counter2`: an *infinite* generator; for every iteration, yield a value from a range.  Repeat for incremented counters recursively.
- `counter3`: a *finite* generator; a simple iteration over a `range()`.

The resulting counters are zipped together, exhausted after the termination of the finite `counter3`.

This example is Python 2 compatible after transforming `yield from` statements to `for` loops, e.g.

```
for i in range(x, stop):
    yield i
```